# C, Reading file elements into arrays, Bad Access Code

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm writing a program that reads in 30 numbers from a file stores them in an array then passes that array to a function which will print out only the even numbers from that array. However, I'm getting a Bad Access Code error in my while statement.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
void even(int numbers[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("error");
    }

    int numbers[30];
    int num = 0;

    int i = 1;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d,", &num) > 0) {
        numbers[i] = num;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    even(numbers);

    return 0;
}

void even(int numbers[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] %2 == 0) {
            printf("%d", numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (fscanf(file, "%d, ", &num) > 0)` is strictly wrong. Please read [`scanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Comment: `printf("error");` --> `printf("error");return -1;`

Answer (score 2):

Your code has mainly 3.5 issues

1. You start with `i = 1` in the first `while` loop.

   ```
   int i = 1;
   /*      ^ this should be 0 */
   while(fscanf(file, "%d,", &num) > 0)
   ```

   Since you start at `1` the `0`th element is not initialized, yet you still try to read it (*read before write*) in `even()` and that, causes undefined behavior.
2. You never check for `i`'s value not to go beyond the number of elements in the array.
3. You try to print `30` elements even though you might read less than that, you must count the total number of elements successfly read and pass that number to `even()`, or at least initialize the array to `0`s.
4. If `fscanf()` succeeds it returns the number of elements matched. This will not cuase a problem in your code but is strictly wrong.

I suggets the following simple fix

```
int i = 0;
while ((fscanf(file, "%d,", &num) == 1) && (i < 30))
```

And

```
void even(int numbers[], size_t count) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] %2 == 0) {
            printf("%d", numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

don't write a function that you can't reuse, it makes no sense.

Comment: fscanf would return zero when your input file has unexpected characters.